# Bootstrap Navbar: How to make external search bar appear in expanded navbar correctly?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap 5 navbar with a search bar then a notifications dropdown and then some collapsible buttons, my question is how do I make this search bar appear in the in the expanded version of the navbar correctly and be hidden when the navbar is collapsed (alongside the buttons, leaving the notifications dropdown visable at all times)?

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
      <form id="search" class="form-inline d-flex me-auto">
         <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search"
            aria-label="Search">
         <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Go</button>
      </form>
      <div class="d-flex">
         <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary me-1" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink"
               data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
               <div id="ex4">
                  <span class="p1 fa-stack fa-2x has-badge" data-count="0" id="badge">
                  <i class="p2 fa fa-bell fa-stack-1x xfa-inverse"></i>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
               <div id="notifications-header">
                  <h1>Notifications</h1>
               </div>
               <div id="notifications">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="navbar-toggler ms-1" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
         <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ms-1 me-1 mt-2 mb-2">Button One</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary ms-1 me-1 mt-2 mb-2">Button Two</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <form name="button-three" class="ms-1 me-1 mt-2 mb-2">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Button Three</button>
               </form>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#navbarSupportedContent {
  max-width: intrinsic;           /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
  max-width: -moz-fit-content;    /* Firefox/Gecko */
  max-width: -webkit-fit-content; /* Chrome */
  max-width: fit-content;  
}
    
.btn {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tL09xuoy/

Answer (score 0):

Anything that you want to not be shown in the navbar on smaller screens can be placed in a `navbar-collapse` division. Since you have your notifications icon between the search form and your other links, you’ll need to have separate collapse divisions. If you change the navbar toggle from working with an ID to working with a class name (I used `. dual-collapse`), then bootstrap will collapse everything.

For things you don’t want collapsed (like your notification icon) you can move that out of the collapsing content using flex order.

I switched the collapse point from your sm to md as things didn’t seem to be fitting nicely at the sm breakpoint, but you can change that back.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #navbarSupportedContent {
        max-width: intrinsic;
        /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
        max-width: -moz-fit-content;
        /* Firefox/Gecko */
        max-width: -webkit-fit-content;
        /* Chrome */
        max-width: fit-content;
    }

    .btn-width-md {
        width: 7.5rem
    }

    @media (min-width:768px) {
        .btn-width-md {
            width: auto;
        }
    }

    .btn {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class=" flex-grow-1">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dual-collapse order-5 order-md-0 collapse navbar-collapse">
            <form id="search" class="input-group form-inline my-3 my-md-0 me-auto">
                <input class="form-control flex-grow-0 w-auto mr-md-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" id="button-addon2"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown order-2">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary me-1" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <div id="ex4">
                    <span class="p1 fa-lg has-badge" data-count="0" id="badge">
                        <i class="p2 fa fa-bell xfa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                <div id="notifications">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-1">
                        <li><a href="#">Notification one</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Notification two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dual-collapse order-4 collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-width-md ms-1 me-1 mt-2 mb-2">Button One</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-width-md ms-1 me-1 mt-2 mb-2">Button Two</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <form name="button-three" class="btn-width-md ms-1 me-1 mt-2 mb-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Button Three</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="order-3">
            <button class="navbar-toggler ms-1" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".dual-collapse" aria-controls="dual-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```